# Foundation button larger than input box?

Tags: css, navigation, zurb-foundation

I have a code pen here to demonstrate: http://codepen.io/earle1jl/pen/OXNrgW

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
  <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>
<div class="top-bar cmichPrimaryNav" id="example-menu">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="menu-text">Application Name</li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <ul class="menu vertical">
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <div class="row collapse">
      <div class="small-8 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      </div>
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <button type="button" class="button">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've added a search box to a top nav, but as you can see, the search button is taller than the search box. In every example I find on the Foundation docs, this is NOT the case. I'm trying to move from Bootstrap to Foundation, so I'm new with this framework. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border: 1px solid transparent;` from `.button` class,

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    transition: background-color .25s ease-out,color .25s ease-out;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: .85em 1em;
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
    font-size: .9rem;
    background-color: #2199e8;
    color: #fefefe;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. This seems to work in the example, but not in the demo that I'm mocking up.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the button element the following: `style="padding:10px;`

So it'll result:

```
<button type="button" class="button" style="padding:10px;">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your css class .button
because you are referring to the default class by bootstrap.

You should create a new class with the same name and set the value as following.

P.S : that would change all you buttons referring to the same class.

```
.button {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        transition: background-color .25s ease-out,color .25s ease-out;
        vertical-align: middle;
        /* border: 1px solid transparent; */
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: .85em 1em;
        margin: 0 0 1rem;
        font-size: .9rem;
        background-color: #2199e8;
        color: #fefefe;
    }
```